# Experimenting, Priming Sugars

Tags: priming, priming-sugar

I've got a 3 gallon batch of bourbon dubbel fermenting, recipe calls for priming with maple syrup, I'm thinking of siphoning off .5 gal to prime with honey and .5 gal to prime with black treacle.

Recipe calls for 1.5 oz maple syrup/gal

Using http://www.northernbrewer.com/priming-sugar-calculator/ 
I plan to use .72 oz honey and .61 oz treacle

Does anyone know if adjusting the priming sugars will result in a noticeable variation in flavor, and possibly carbonation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I experimented many years ago with splitting a batch and priming with corn sugar, table sugar, DME, maple syrup, honey, force carbing and a couple others I can't recall.  I calculated to try to make sure all would have the same level of carbonation.  After 2 months, I held a blind tasting.  No one could distinguish one from the other or had a preference for any method.

Answer (score 1):

Your CO2 volume will be directly affected by how fermentable your priming sugar is.  Simple sugars like table sugar or corn sugar are very fermentable, so you can use smaller amounts of them, meaning they're less likely to influence the taste.  ISTR that treacle isn't as fermentable, so you'll get lower CO2 volumes and likely a noticable flavor.

FWIW, I brewed a bourbon dubbel and primed it with maple syrup and could't taste the syrup at all.